# Meteor React: What is the simplest way to ensure a user is logged in before rendergin a page?

Tags: meteor, meteor-react, meteor-useraccounts

### Situation:

- I'm using React in a Meteor app.
- My packages for authentication: `accounts-password`; `useraccounts:core`
- I also use the `gadicc:blaze-react-component` to render the `{{> atForm }}` template in my react component =>`<Blaze template="atForm" />`

### Problem:

I don't know what should be the proper syntax to secure a specific page as described in the [useraccounts guide](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#content-protection) **but with react**.

Lets suppose that I want to secure `<Mypage />` imported from './mypage.jsx'

How can I call `{{> ensureSignedIn template="myTemplate"}}` and reaplace *"myTemplate"* by `<Mypage />` ?

I tried `<Blaze template="atForm" template={Mypage} />` without success...

Is it even possible to make something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

With `kadira:flow-router` Meteor's package, using `react-layout` and `useraccounts:flow-routing`, I can do something like that:

```
FlowRouter.route('/private', {
  triggersEnter: [AccountsTemplates.ensureSignedIn],
  action: function() {
    ReactLayout.render(Mypage, {myprops: myprops.value});
  }
});
```

It seems that it all happens into `triggersEnter: [...]` key.

More details [here](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/flow-routing#content-protection).

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Meteor.userId()` in `ComponentWillMount()`, set state and check it in `render()`. Or use some kind of checkings in your router